# Spring security acl with spring boot 2 integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I googled a lot for a spring security acl with **spring boot 2** demo, But there is nothing. Anyone have an example to share with me?

Comment: Go through [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl)  link

Comment: it's work with spring boot 1 not 2.